# Separate request building and execution

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a few kinds of requests that have different payloads (or no payload at all). I want to separate request building from its execution, so I have RequestFactory that produces abstract Request and RequestExecutor that has method execute(request). The problem is that logic of request execution is coupled with its type, so I would need to have cases like this:

```
if(request instanceof SomeTypeOfRequest) ((SomeTypeOfRequest) request).getPayload()
```

Another approach is to have execute method inside Request but that leads to having all of RequestExecutor dependencies inside RequestFactory as I need them to build a request. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I can use visitor. It sort of combines this two approaches. I just need to have execute(RequestExecutor) method in Request interface

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).